# CSS: arranging floating elements

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have 3 block elements (2 navbars and one picture) in one container, all are floating and have a fluid width. The picture is in-between the navbars, so my left navbar and the pic have float:left and the right navbar has float:right.

My goal is to get the picture underneath the navbars on mobile devices. To do so I thought I just have to add float:none to the pic in my media query but the result is the right navbar positioning under the pic.

Is there maybe a way to re-arrange the divs in mobile-view? 
Best solution would be a trick to tell the floating elements in which order they should float.

[image]

Comment: provide the jsfiddle or source code of html css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `clear:both`.. anyways, here's one way around it;you can adjust the width's and what not, but you get the idea: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U6KWc/). Also, note that because all items are floating.. you can place the image AFTER both navbars & have it displayed in the center at larger widths.

Comment: Thinking too complex and overlooking simple maths.. Thank you